# Plotting from matrix element

Tags: plotting, matrix, manipulate

I am struggling with a function creating a manipulate of a plot, where the input functions are in form of matrix element.
First I define the matrix:

```
HBdG[eta_] := {{((p)^2)/(2 m) - μ + eta β, 0, 0, Subscript[Δ, 0] + Subscript[Δ, 3]}, 
 {0, (p)^2/(2 m) - μ - eta β, -Subscript[Δ, 0] + Subscript[Δ, 3], 0},
 {0, -Subscript[Δ, 0] - Subscript[Δ, 3], -(p^2)/(2 m) + μ - eta β, 0}, 
 {Subscript[Δ, 0] - Subscript[Δ, 3], 0, 0, -(p)^2/(2 m) + μ + eta β}}
```

that is a 4*4 matrix with parameters.
Then I define a matrix-like function calculating eigenvalues of the HBdG natrix with respect to parameter eta:

```
eigenvalues[eta_] := Eigenvalues[HBdG[eta]]
```

and finally I would like to plot the energy spectrum via yet defined function eigenvalues into manipulate:

```
tralalal[eta_] := Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate[eigenvalues[eta]], {p, -(3/10^16), 3/10^16}, 
    PlotRange -> {-(3/10^3), 3/10^3}], {β, 0, 1/10^3}, 
    {μ, 0, 1/10^3}, {m, 9.109 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \({\(-31\)}\)]\)}, 
    {Subscript[Δ, 0], 1/10^8, 1/10^3}, {Subscript[Δ, 3], 0, 1/10^3}]
```

I would like to end up with a manipulate of a plot with four functions of "p" with parameters Mu,m,Delta0 and Delta3, while having the ability to switch values of "eta".
But I end up just with plain plot... Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Variable parameters in `manipulate` are localized, that means they are different from a parameter with the same name outside of `Manipulate`. Further your specification of m is wrong syntax. Simply say m=...